# Property of trigonometric function, simple question

Tags: calculus

I was just curious, does there exist a trigonometric function, $f(x)$, where it has the property:

$$\frac{f(a)}{f(b)}=f \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)$$

If yes, which trigonometric function and how is that true.

If no, why?

Comment: aren't all such functions either discontinuous or linear ?

Comment: "Linear" such as a "linear function"?

Comment: Not just linear - if linear, they'd have to be the identity. It's more like log-linear - $f(x)=x^n$ has this property. That's the only continuous function defined.

Comment: Because then no, functions like $x^2$ have this property. $\frac{a^2}{b^2}=\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^2$

Comment: What counts as a "trigonometric function"?

Comment: Oh ok good point

Comment: Functions like $sin(x), cos(x), tan(x)$ along with their hyperbolic, reciprocal, and inverse counterparts

Comment: Writing $f(x)=e^{g(\ln x)}$ makes $g$ an additive function, $g(x+y)=g(x)+g(y)$. As others have remarked, such $g$ is either awfully discontinuous or of the form $g(x)=cx$. Hence $f(x)=x^c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're only considering sine, cosine, and tangent, along with their hyperbolic, reciprocal, and inverse counterparts, then that's 24 functions, and I suppose you could list them all and prove that each one doesn't satisfy the identity.

If the domain of definition of $f$ is the positive real numbers, and $f$ is continuous, then as Thomas and Hagen have pointed out, $f(x)=x^c$. These are arguably "trigonometric" in some sense, since the usual trig functions are built out of exponentials and logarithms, and we can write $x^c=e^{(c\log x)}$.

If the domain of definition includes the negative numbers, then the multiplicative group of units gains an extra generator $-1$, so we can get extra solutions of the form $f(x)=|x|\,x^c$.

If $f$ doesn't have to be continuous, we can get more creative! Let
$$f(x)=\lim_{a\to+\infty}\tanh(ax).$$
This function satisfies the required identity, and it's built upon a trigonometric function pretty directly. The function $f$ is better known as the [signum function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).

Edit ...Ha, it occurs to me that the sign function is just $|x|\,x^{-1}$, so it's not really a new solution. Of course, we have to be careful when we define $f(0)$ either way.